# whereis Gstreamer - located in two paths - causing issues

Tags: package-management, path, which, installer-anaconda, gstreamer

Gstreamer doesn't run as expected when executed from the command line.

It turns out all the plugins I am installing are defaulting to one location while when I'm running gstreamer its opening from the other.

```
whereis gst-launch-1.0

gst-launch-1: /usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 /home/lewis/anaconda3/bin/gst-launch-1.0
```

on the other hand

```
which gst-launch-1.0

/home/lewis/anaconda3/bin/gst-launch-1.0
```

my path

```
$PATH

bash: /home/lewis/anaconda3/bin:/home/lewis/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
```

What do I do in this situation?

Is there a way to remove one completely?

I believe the /usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 is the correct version - shall i reorder my $PATH variable to have /usr/bin/ appear first?

Will this have any other consequences?